# Can OpenCV cv::resize() change the min and max values of the image? (Using INTER_LINEAR method)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-resizing, opencv3.0, linear-interpolation

Let us say I have a greyscale image(640 × 480 size) with min pixel intensity = 23 and max intensity = 245.

If I resize it using `cv::resize()` with `INTER_LINEAR` to 1920×1080, can the min and max intensities change? My min intensity has become 25 and max intensity 247. Any possible wrong usage which leads to this?

Is it possible to restrict the `cv::resize` to only resize within the min max values?

I have tried normalizing the image after resize with `NORM_MINMAX` and original min max values but the results do not look the same. I don't have the option of using `INTER_NEAREST`. It looks extremely blurred.

I want to retain the original min max values but resize using INTER_LINEAR. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to keep the min/max values with any methods using an interpolation in my opinion. See [Bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) for more information and to understand why min/max values could be not present anymore in the resized image.

If you want to retain the original min/max, you will have to post process manually **without any guarantee** that the visual result will be good.

Possible solution:

- one image resized with `INTER_LINEAR`
- another one with `INTER_NEAREST`
- fuse the two images:

  - `I_res(i,j)=I_near(i,j)` when `I_near(i,j)==min or max`
  - `I_res(i,j)=I_linear(i,j)` otherwise

But this way, you mess with the formula used to do the linear interpolation.

Comment: Thanks @Catree If I resize the image and then normalize the new image between the original minmax values, will I be in for anything unforeseen? That seems to be working for now.

Comment: Yes, range normalization should work (should be preferred over my approach) also.